# Access .rds file from Python

Tags: python, r

I am working on a project where I have got an .rds file which consist of trained model as per my requirement generated by R code.

Now I need to load the trained model in python and use it in processing the records.

Is there any way to do so? If not what are the alternatives.

Thanks

Comment: Look at this website, maybe this can help too. http://mgimond.github.io/ES218/Week02b.html

Answer (score 2):

We can use feather:

```
import feather
path = 'my_data.feather'
feather.write_dataframe(df, path)
df = feather.read_dataframe(path)
```

Comment: Feather seems to be a good tool. After loading a trained model in rds file I need to make a call in the same R session to get the prediction. I am trying it using rpy2. Not got the success though. 
dataframe to R session can be passed using

import rpy2.robjects as ro
dataRec = ro.DataFrame({ "protodesc":protodesc ,"serverflag":serverflag ,....}
#Assigning to R object.
ro.globalenv['test'] = dataRec;
ro.r('predboom<-predict(fit, test, type="response")')

Getting error from last line
rpy2.rinterface.RRuntimeError: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'skew1' not found

Comment: I finally ended up moving completely to python and used pickle to save my trained model and read it back.
[link](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html)